# DataGrip showing prints during a transaction

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, update, datagrip

I have a long running update query, for this reason I used the old well known trick of dividing the query in smaller chunks of 1000 to be print the status of the query and calm the anxiety.

Unfortunately DataGrip seems to write to output all the print at the end of the query, witch makes it useless.
[image]
Is it possible to print the updates the same way as Visual Studio?
[image]

Comment: DataGrip cannot do that yet. Can you please create a feature request here? 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: Please dont post text information as image

Answer (score 1):

The `PRINT` statement as you have experienced will not display right away. When you would like to see progress, you can use `RAISERROR` with `NOWAIT` for that.v

```
DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(200) = CONCAT('Processing chunk ', @currChunk, ' of ', @numChunks);
RAISERROR(@Msg, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
```

[image]

Shows my result from my testscript:

```
DECLARE @currChunk INT = 1;
DECLARE @numChunks INT = 20;

WHILE @currChunk < @numChunks
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(200) = CONCAT('Processing chunk ', @currChunk, ' of ', @numChunks);
    RAISERROR(@Msg, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

    SET @currChunk = @currChunk + 1;

    WAITFOR  DELAY '00:00:02'   /*delay for simulating progress*/

END;
```

See also:
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-print-and-sql-server-raiserror-statements/

Comment: Thanks for the answer the article is also interesting. I tried using raiserror as you suggested but DataGrip in the output window is not showing any progress.

Comment: @s.demuro, it's up to the application code to display messages as they become available. If DataGroup doesn't show those immediately even with the `NOWAIT` option, it seems it was not coded to do that like SSMS. Even SSMS will start buffering and delay display when there are many messages.

Answer (score 0):

In DataGrip 2023.1 suggested code:

```sql
DECLARE @currChunk INT = 1;
DECLARE @numChunks INT = 20;

WHILE @currChunk < @numChunks
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(200) = CONCAT('Processing chunk ', @currChunk, ' of ', @numChunks);
    RAISERROR(@Msg, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

    SET @currChunk = @currChunk + 1;

    WAITFOR  DELAY '00:00:02'   /*delay for simulating progress*/

END;
```

shows a valid output in console output.

[image: PRINT WORKS CORRECTLY IN DATAGRIP]